# How can I fix a Debian VM booting to a black screen?

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine

I have a VDI file with Debian installed on it. When I start the VM, GRUB is run and after choosing the system's version (restore or normal boot) a black screen appears.

How can I diagnose what the trouble is?

Comment: Huh, I have the same problem and asked a question about [eight hours before you](http://superuser.com/q/830361/207935).

Comment: Were you able to boot the source machine successfully with which you created that `vdi`? Just curious to know if that the image was cloned and copied without corruption?

Comment: @Vembu - In my case, the image booted and was working perfectly fine until I installed Guest Additions. I'm curious to know if OP installed Guest Additions and if they can boot into recovery mode.

Comment: @Vembu, the source machine works fine and copied are also well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the VM for the same system architecture (amd64 vs i386) ? You could edit grub command line (probably ctrl-x or 'e', depending on grub) and edit kernel command line to remove "quiet" flag; and see if it shows something

Comment: Yep. The message was "Loading current ramdisk" and load faulted. Accidentaly, I created the VM with i386 arch. versus needed amd64. Foolish, yeah. And now I'm already starting my issues, thanks.